# data extange between forms in managed c++

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, managed-c++

I need to get data from form2->textBox and put to form1->textBox;

In Form1.h i write

```
#pragma once
#include "Form2.h"

Form2^ f2 = gcnew Form2();
f2->ShowDialog();
```

and that WORKS! But after that i add to Form2.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Form1.h"
```

to write

```
Form1^ f1;
f1->textBox1->Text = this.textBox1->Text;
```

But that gives me lots of errors like

```
Form1, Form2, f1, f2 : undeclared identifiers
```

## Here is the full code

#### Form1.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Form2.h"

namespace test76 {

    using namespace System;
    ....

    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();              
        }

    protected:          
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    protected: 
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;

    private:
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            ....

        }
#pragma endregion

    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                Form2^ f2 = gcnew Form2();
                f2->ShowDialog();

             }
    };
}
```

#### Form2.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Form1.h"  //  <- do I need to put it here?


namespace test76 {

    using namespace System;
    ....

    public ref class Form2 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form2(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();              
        }

    protected:          
        ~Form2()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    protected: 
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;

    private:
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            ....

        }
#pragma endregion

    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                Form1->textBox1->Text = textBox1->Text;
             }
    };
}
```

#### Entry Point

```
// test76.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"

using namespace test76;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
    return 0;
}
```

Without #include "Form2.h" The error is Form1 : undeclared identifier in Form2.h, button1_Click,

With #include "Form2.h" gives me lots of errors like Form1, Form2, f2 : undeclared identifiers

Comment: You have a circular #include dependency, form1.h includes form2.h and form2.h includes form1.h.  That can't work, C++ uses a single-pass compiler.  You have to do the .h/.cpp dance and use a forward declaration.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't initialized your `textBox1`I say look like because I don't see the designer code behind in your `Form1.h`(but that is just an off the cuff guess, look for something like `Windows Form Designer generated code` in your header).

Specifically down to the issue of your error(s)

If you are wanting to generate the textbox at runtime then something like this will allow for access to the text box

```
int main (array <System :: String ^> ^ args)
{
   // Run the application 

   auto form = gcnew MyForm();
   auto myTextBox = gcnew Windows::Forms::TextBox();
   myTextBox->Name = "myTxtBox";
   myTextBox->Text = "This is my txt box";
   form->Controls->Add(myTextBox);
   Application::Run(form);

   // return to main
   return 0;
}
```

However if you are using the designer and have named the control `textBox1` then I'd recommend you check the properties of your designer and ensure that the `Modifiers` property is set to something other than `Private` and that your `Name` property is matching. If both of those are true then the following should work.

```
int main (array <System :: String ^> ^ args)
{
   // Run the application 

   auto form = gcnew MyForm();
   form->myDesignTimeTextbox->Text = "I am a design time textbox";
   Application::Run(form);

   // return to main
   return 0;
}
```

### Using Two Forms at the Same Time

While I'm sure there are other ways to do this, one sure fire way is to instantiate a new instance of the existing form (or an instance of a another form class), clear its contents and append your new content to the form.(note I am omitting the generated code from the example as it is pretty verbose) Look at the `button1_Click event`

### Example

#### The form class

```
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
   {
   public:
      MyForm(void)
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         //
         //TODO: Add the constructor code here
         //
      }

   protected:
      /// <summary>
      /// Clean up any resources being used.
      /// </summary>
      ~MyForm()
      {
         if (components)
         {
            delete components;
         }
      }
   public: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  myDesignTimeTextbox;
   protected: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
   public: 

   public: 
   protected: 

   protected: 

   protected: 

   private:
      /// <summary>
      /// Required designer variable.
      /// </summary>
      System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
 //omitted for brevity
//I have a button named button1 and a TextBox named myDesignTimeTextbox
#pragma endregion

   private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
            {
               this->myDesignTimeTextbox->Text = L"You clicked Teh Button, You R Win";

               //create new form and add a textbox
               auto form2 = gcnew MyForm();
               form2->Controls->Clear();
               auto getTxt = gcnew TextBox();
               getTxt->Name = L"Generated_Textbox";

               //the content of the txtbox will be that of the design Time text box
               getTxt->Text = myDesignTimeTextbox->Text;
               form2->Controls->Add(getTxt);

               form2->ShowDialog();
            }

   };
```

#### Entry Point

```
 int main (array  ^ args)
   {
      // Run the application 
      auto form1 = gcnew MyForm();

      Application::Run(form1);

      // return to main
      return 0;
   }
```

Note* In case you didn't already know, the keyword [auto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k3ybftz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a way to not have to specify the type if it is known.

Comment: Thats not exactly what i need.U've passed the data to Form2, but what I need is to pass data from Form2 to Form1 AFTER that. I gave u the full code in title post.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is in your `Form2.h` code:

```
//Form2.h
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                Form1->textBox1->Text = textBox1->Text;
         }
```

You can't use `Form1->textBox1` directly. You need a variable that can catch the address/point to running `form1`.
Modify it to something like this:

```
//Form1.h
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            Form2^ f2 = gcnew Form2(this);
            f2->ShowDialog();
         }

//Form2
private: Form1^ f1;
Form2(Form1^ f)
{ f1=f; }
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
         { f1->textBox1->Text = textBox1->Text; }
```